# HTML Forms to display comments

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating forms on an HTML web page so that visitors can add comments about my page. This includes different types of forms and I am struggling on an if else statement for the radio button. My html code is posted blow and then the php linking to it is posted below that. PLEASE HELP!!!

```
<html>
<form action="process_comment.php"  method="post">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
    <br>
</form>

<form action="process_comment.php" method="post" >
    Do you like this page?
    <input type = "radio" name = "like" value = "0"> Yes
    <input type = "radio" name = "like" value = "1"> No
    <br>
<input type="submit" value ="go" /><br>
</form>
</html>


<?php
$userName=$_POST["username"];
echo "Hello <b>$userName</b>!<br>";
?>   

<?php
$like = $_POST["like"];
if($like = "post") {
    echo "I am happy that you <b>like</b> this page :)";
}   else {
    echo "I am sorry that you <b>do not like</b> my page :(";
}
?>
```

Comment: Add some details about the problem you are facing.

Comment: As per your code you are using two forms and one submit action. Try  to merge both the forms.

Comment: $_POST["like"]  will be either 0 or 1 . So your if statement should be if($like) { . Also there  cannot be two forms. Every element must be in a single form.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two forms and one action try below code and merge both forms in one.

```
<html>
    <form action="process_comment.php"  method="post">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
        <br>

        Do you like this page?
        <input type = "radio" name = "like" value = "0"> Yes
        <input type = "radio" name = "like" value = "1"> No
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value ="go" /><br>
    </form>
 </html>
```

And in process_comment.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])
    {

      $userName=$_POST["username"];
      echo "Hello <b>$userName</b>!<br>";
      $like = $_POST["like"];
      if($like) {
        echo "I am happy that you <b>like</b> this page :)";
      }   
      else {
        echo "I am sorry that you <b>do not like</b> my page :(";
      }
    }
 ?>
```

If value is 1 or 0 you can use variable in if condition as it works as true or false.

Comment: This is the perfect answer to your question. Thumbs up (y)